Copyright of advertising banner in background of a USAF footage from 1972
Recently i come across these footages: https://catalog.archives.gov/id/71583, it's not available on the Catalog yet but it have been digitized and i successfully requested the MP4 files, i want to upload this to Wikimedia Commons for everyone to access and i checked for potentially copyrighted materials. Reel 1 seem fine, but Reel 2 at 18:12 to 18:22 contains these advertising banners:


Do i have to cut/blur/censoring those banners?
Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad English

If posting to Wikimedia were to be an infringement, wouldn't posting here also be an infringement?

Personally i think take a screenshot and post it here would be fair use because the full frame is only 720x480 while the banners only display a fraction of a full frame (resolution comparable to fair use image on Wikipedia), also the banners are partially obstructed too


The MP4 video were also 720x480 and suffers heavily from lossy compression both from Digital Betacam and H264 encoding

